# URL Redirect rule for .cfm files using regex

Tags: url, redirect, coldfusion

I am trying to create a regex rule for old URLs created with ColdFusion that can redirect to the new version of the page. For example:

https://www.example.co.uk/article/1234/1234_home.cfm
should point to
https://www.example.co.uk/article/1234/

etc.

I have hundreds of pages this is required for so this needs to be a regex rather than implemented on each individual page.

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Please describe what the regex exactly should do and also describe what you already tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I would like the regex to remove "_home.cfm" + everything before that up to the trailling slash in the URL as per the example. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: could you treat it as a list with / as the delimiter, and just remove the last list item?

Comment: Which web server are you using? We've rewrittien most of our generic URL redirect rules, like the one you need, to IIS instead of passing it on for the ColdFusion service to process. It was faster & resulted in less overhead.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` or the like would be more appropriate for this task. Redirecting before it hits ColdFusion would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You might want to adjust the:

```
[0-9]{4,4}
```

Section of the expression, depending on how many digits you wish to capture:

```
<cfset oldurl = "https://www.example.co.uk/article/1234/1234_home.cfm">
<cfset newurl = REReplaceNoCase(oldurl,"(.*)[0-9]{4,4}_home\.cfm$","\1")>
```